# C++ array initialized in function cannot be accessed in main

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function used to initialize array in C++. after the initialization, main can not access the data in the array. Don't know why. Any help?

```
void testArray(int *listPtr)

{
   listPtr=new int[2]; 
   listPtr[0]=0;
   listPtr[1]=1;


}// end testArray

void main()
{
   int *list;
   testArray(list);
   cout<<list[0]<<list[1]<<endl; // this gives some random output
} // end main
```

Comment: C++ has value semantics and also requires `main` to return `int`.

Comment: @chris The standard actually allows you to omit a return in main. (A `return 0;` is implied. Strange but true.)

Comment: @RaymondChen, I meant the return type. It's `void` in the question :)

Comment: Your code, among other things, misses a `delete[]`. If you do not want an object to live "forever" (i.e. until your program terminates), you have to `delete[]` everything which was allocated with `new[]`. Or even better, as one answer says, forget about dynamically allocated arrays and use `std::vector`.

Comment: @chris Ah, sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the pointer is passed by value. The argument to the function is copied, and the first line of your function replaces the local copy of the pointer with the result of the new expression. The original copy of your pointer, back in `main()`, is unaffected by this.

You can "fix" this by either passing the pointer by reference:

```
void testArray(int*& listPtr)
{

    listPtr = new int[2]; 
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    int* list = 0;
    testArray(list);
    // ...
    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

or by passing a pointer to the pointer:

```
void testArray(int** listPtr)
{
    *listPtr = new int[2];
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    int* list = 0;
    testArray(&list);
    // ...
    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

or, better still, by using a C++ standard library container that provides value semantics (in conjunction with a reference argument):

```
void testVec(std::vector<int>& list)
{
    list.resize(2);
    list[0] = 0;
    list[1] = 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> list;
    testVec(list);
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

### Analogy time:

The problem arises because a pointer is a separate entity (object) that *points to* some other object. Pointers can be copied just as regular objects can, and there is no special consideration given to them to make sure that the thing they point to is updated to reflect any change made to the pointer. A reference is a different beast entirely. Once a reference has been *bound* to some object, it is (to all intents and purposes) indistinguishable from the object itself; any operation on the reference is an operation on the underlying object. You can think of it as though you possess a cat named Fluffy, and you let your friend borrow Fluffy; but your friend calls her Buffy. It's the same cat, and if your friend trims her claws, the next time you see Fluffy, she'll have trimmed claws.

For the pointer example, you have Fluffy, and you give your friend a note with Fluffy's address written on it. Your friend goes and gets a new cat, and writes the new cat's address on top of the note you gave them. Now, when your friend trims the claws of the new cat, nothing at all happens to Fluffy. The note just allows your friend to go to the place where Fluffy lives; right up to the point where your friend overwrites the note with the address of some other cat.

References make it much easier to reason about the behaviour of your code, and should be preferred in almost all situations.

Comment: Your first two examples keep the memory leak of the original code.

Comment: What memory leak? The pointer was uninitialised before the call to testArray() (which itself, is bad, but not a leak) and the memory is freed when this trivial program terminates. Obviously in any non-trivial program you would prefer to wrap these pointers up in a smart pointer to take care of the resource management for you, but that is not really the focus of this question.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, see my comment above; however I have edited my answer to initialise the pointers to 0 (which is always a good idea), and to delete immediately prior to return. The other potential leak is when a pointer to an already allocated array is passed into testArray(), but the original code from the question clearly does not do this.

Comment: I think the OP is still at a level where it's just good practice to delete everything at the end. To learn that some objects may very well never be deleted is for advanced programmers IMO.

Answer (score 5):

You need pass ***by reference***, so that the change to the pointer `listPtr` itself can be passed out to the outter variable. Remember, you are changing the value of "the pointer itself", which is invisible to the caller if pass ***by value***.

```
void testArray(int * &listPtr)
{
   listPtr=new int[2]; 
   listPtr[0]=0;
   listPtr[1]=1;
}// end testArray
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pass by reference, so that listPtr get updated while initializing it in testarray function.

To do that do the following -

```
void testArray(int * &listPtr)
{
   listPtr=new int[2]; 
   listPtr[0]=0;
   listPtr[1]=1;
}
```

If you are confused about the above solution you can simply declare and initialize this one globally.